# Cannot connect to wpa2 enterprise using esp32

Tags: wifi, esp32

I am trying to connect an esp32 device to the university wifi network which is a wpa2 enterprise.
Below is the code I have tried but I am unable to connect. It is from this [link](https://github.com/martinius96/ESP32-eduroam/blob/master/2021/experimental_example/experimental_example.ino). The only changes I make to the code is adding my username (`EAP_IDENTITY`) and password. I am not sure if the university uses radius servers. I don't really understand the role of the test certificate so I don't make any changes to it.

Any help would be appreciated

```
#include <WiFi.h> //Wifi library
#include "esp_wpa2.h" //wpa2 library for connections to Enterprise networks

//Identity for user with password related to his realm (organization)
//Available option of anonymous identity for federation of RADIUS servers or 1st Domain RADIUS servers

//#define EAP_ANONYMOUS_IDENTITY "anonymous@tuke.sk" //anonymous@example.com, or you can use also nickname@example.com
#define EAP_IDENTITY "username@tuke.sk" //nickname@example.com, at some organizations should work nickname only without realm, but it is not recommended
#define EAP_PASSWORD "password" //password for eduroam account

//SSID NAME
const char* ssid = "eduroam"; // eduroam SSID

//Root CA cert (DigiCert Assured ID Root CA) in .pem format from:
//https://uvt.tuke.sk/wps/portal/uv/sluzby/bezdrotove-siete-wifi-na-tuke/prirucka-pouzivatela-bezdrotovej-siete-eduroam

const static char* test_root_ca PROGMEM = \
    "-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\n" \
    "MIIDtzCCAp+gAwIBAgIQDOfg5RfYRv6P5WD8G/AwOTANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBl\n" \
    "MQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3\n" \
    "d3cuZGlnaWNlcnQuY29tMSQwIgYDVQQDExtEaWdpQ2VydCBBc3N1cmVkIElEIFJv\n" \
    "b3QgQ0EwHhcNMDYxMTEwMDAwMDAwWhcNMzExMTEwMDAwMDAwWjBlMQswCQYDVQQG\n" \
    "EwJVUzEVMBMGA1UEChMMRGlnaUNlcnQgSW5jMRkwFwYDVQQLExB3d3cuZGlnaWNl\n" \
    "cnQuY29tMSQwIgYDVQQDExtEaWdpQ2VydCBBc3N1cmVkIElEIFJvb3QgQ0EwggEi\n" \
    "MA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4IBDwAwggEKAoIBAQCtDhXO5EOAXLGH87dg+XESpa7c\n" \
    "JpSIqvTO9SA5KFhgDPiA2qkVlTJhPLWxKISKityfCgyDF3qPkKyK53lTXDGEKvYP\n" \
    "mDI2dsze3Tyoou9q+yHyUmHfnyDXH+Kx2f4YZNISW1/5WBg1vEfNoTb5a3/UsDg+\n" \
    "wRvDjDPZ2C8Y/igPs6eD1sNuRMBhNZYW/lmci3Zt1/GiSw0r/wty2p5g0I6QNcZ4\n" \
    "VYcgoc/lbQrISXwxmDNsIumH0DJaoroTghHtORedmTpyoeb6pNnVFzF1roV9Iq4/\n" \
    "AUaG9ih5yLHa5FcXxH4cDrC0kqZWs72yl+2qp/C3xag/lRbQ/6GW6whfGHdPAgMB\n" \
    "AAGjYzBhMA4GA1UdDwEB/wQEAwIBhjAPBgNVHRMBAf8EBTADAQH/MB0GA1UdDgQW\n" \
    "BBRF66Kv9JLLgjEtUYunpyGd823IDzAfBgNVHSMEGDAWgBRF66Kv9JLLgjEtUYun\n" \
    "pyGd823IDzANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFAAOCAQEAog683+Lt8ONyc3pklL/3cmbYMuRC\n" \
    "dWKuh+vy1dneVrOfzM4UKLkNl2BcEkxY5NM9g0lFWJc1aRqoR+pWxnmrEthngYTf\n" \
    "fwk8lOa4JiwgvT2zKIn3X/8i4peEH+ll74fg38FnSbNd67IJKusm7Xi+fT8r87cm\n" \
    "NW1fiQG2SVufAQWbqz0lwcy2f8Lxb4bG+mRo64EtlOtCt/qMHt1i8b5QZ7dsvfPx\n" \
    "H2sMNgcWfzd8qVttevESRmCD1ycEvkvOl77DZypoEd+A5wwzZr8TDRRu838fYxAe\n" \
    "+o0bJW1sj6W3YQGx0qMmoRBxna3iw/nDmVG3KwcIzi7mULKn+gpFL6Lw8g==\n" \
    "-----END CERTIFICATE-----\n";

void setup() {
  Serial.begin(115200);
  delay(10);
  Serial.println();
  Serial.print(F("Connecting to network: "));
  Serial.println(ssid);
  WiFi.disconnect(true);  //disconnect form wifi to set new wifi connection
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA); //init wifi mode
  esp_wifi_sta_wpa2_ent_set_ca_cert((uint8_t *)test_root_ca, strlen(test_root_ca) + 1);
  //esp_wifi_sta_wpa2_ent_set_ca_cert((uint8_t *)test_root_ca, strlen(test_root_ca));
  //esp_wifi_sta_wpa2_ent_set_identity((uint8_t *)EAP_ANONYMOUS_IDENTITY, strlen(EAP_ANONYMOUS_IDENTITY));
  esp_wifi_sta_wpa2_ent_set_username((uint8_t *)EAP_IDENTITY, strlen(EAP_IDENTITY));
  esp_wifi_sta_wpa2_ent_set_password((uint8_t *)EAP_PASSWORD, strlen(EAP_PASSWORD));
  esp_wpa2_config_t config = WPA2_CONFIG_INIT_DEFAULT(); //set config settings to default
  esp_wifi_sta_wpa2_ent_enable(&config); //set config settings to enable function
  WiFi.begin(ssid); //connect to wifi
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
    delay(500);
    Serial.print(F("."));
  }
  Serial.println("");
  Serial.println(F("WiFi is connected!"));
  Serial.println(F("IP address set: "));
  Serial.println(WiFi.localIP()); //print LAN IP
}
void loop() {

}
```